# Return variable with GRASS GIS on a Windows machine

Tags: grass-gis, grass.script

How do I return a variable in GRASS GIS on a Windows machine?

For example I set a list of files to define my region. I already [figured out](https://grass.osgeo.org/grass64/manuals/variables.html) that I can't use the bash command `export`, I need to use `set` instead. The command should be okay, but it doesn't return `$MAPS`.

```cmd
set MAPS=`g.mlist type=rast sep=, pat="*"`  
g.region rast=$MAPS -p
```

I tried already to check if the variable is set (`echo $MAPS`), but without success.

Comment: Those back ticks are linux syntax to evaluate what's inside of them first. It won't work on windows to capture output in a variable. This is a frustrating problem I've faced a lot too. The best I've been able to find is something like `FOR /F "delims=" %i IN ('echo "Hello World"') DO set output=%i` then `echo %output%` gives "Hello World" from http://stackoverflow.com/questions/108439/how-do-i-get-the-result-of-a-command-in-a-variable-in-windows. But it's so cumbersome that at this point I usually switch to python. Hopefully you get a good answer because I'd like to see it too.

Comment: Thx @user55937, I think I will give up and switch back to Linux... It's just too frustrating.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That's because $MAPS doesn't exist from windows command line.

You need to call variables with %MAPS% (surrounded by % sign).

But also consider that grass when installed either from the grass site using the stand alone installer or osgeo4w they both come with MSYS - a unix like shell. You can use that instead which lets you stay with bash like syntax.

Comment: It doesn't work, I tried a `echo %MAPS%` and it returns just the variable name. I'll try to use MSYS that sounds like a what I want...

Comment: It seams like `cmd` is not fully loaded. If I set `set test=123` and let it return directly `echo %test%` it just print `%test%`. Normally it only does that in `cmd` when the variable is not set. By the way with `MSYS` I can't run `grass64`, it seem like something is wrong implemented. Maybe I should reinstall `OSGeo4W` or just switch into the virtual machine.